# I can't read sucessfully from an RssFeed React-Native, State remains empty

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am trying to read from rssfeed and I have used `Array.from()` for be able to map through the response from `XMLHttpRequest()` and it returns a blank state with no errors whatsoever. Please assist me

```
const [rssfeed, setrssfeed] = useState(null);
const [feedname, setfeedname] = useState(null);
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(rssfeed);
  }, [rssfeed]);

  async function getnewsfeed() {
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = () => {
      if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
        const response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        setfeedname(response.feed.title);
        Array.from(response, (data) => {
          setrssfeed((rssfeed) => [
            {
              ...rssfeed,
              title: data.items.title,
              image: data.items.thumbnail,
            },
          ]);
        });
      }
    };
    request.open(
      "GET",
      "https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=http%3A%2F%2Ffeeds2.feedburner.com%2FLatestGeneralNews",
      true
    );
    request.send();
  }
```

Comment: your response is a JSON object I believe and not an array. Please share your response object if you need help with the map function and setting state from json response object.

Comment: @sushrut619 I don't understand your needs please. I created an `XMLHttpRequest()` which has a response object after connection has been made. So I parse the response object into json and after that I want to `map()` through the json object so I use `Array.from()` to send the json response to an array so that I can map through. That is where my problem lies. The mapping through the json response

Comment: Please read the documentation for [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from). You are not using it correctly. It does not work on objects the way you want it to work because as you mentioned yourself your response is json and not an array. You could use ```Object.keys(response).map(...)``` or some other alternative to map over object properties.

Comment: @sushrut619 Awesome thanks for pointing me in the right direction..